# Make a child element opaque in a div that is not opaque

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an element opaque, that's in a `<div>` that is not opaque. I tried simply applying `opacity: 1`, but the background still showed through the element. I also tried adding `!important` to the attribute.
Thanks!

Comment: Not possible, yet... Child will inherit opacity of parent.

Comment: You could try `rbga` + alpha, instead of `opacity`.

Answer (score 4):

#### If the `<div>` has a `background-color`

Instead of using `opacity` on the `<div>`, you can use [`background-color: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) to specify its background color. Just replace red, green, blue and alpha with their corresponding values.

#### If the `<div>` has a `background-image`

It is not trivially possible. But one workaround would be to have 2 `<div>`s, one over the other. The lower `<div>` would be non-opaque, and have a background. The upper `<div>` would have your content. Use `z-index` to place the div with the content above the div containing the background image.

Another workaround would be to actually have a transparent PNG image as the background-image of the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, *opacity* is inherited (mandatory, cannot override), if the parent `<div>` you're using uses a background image, you have to move the element outside, maybe using absolute position, to locate it over the non-opaque one. If the parent `<div>` just have a color background and you make a percent transparent, easy!... you need to assign a *RGBA* color background (and opacity 1, of course).

I recommend a tool I've found useful: http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/ so you can calculate the rgba value properly. That's it

Answer (score 1):

If your parent div simply has a background color or background image, then you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <span>Hello World</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#parent:after{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background: url('someimage.png') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: -1;
}
```