# How to make a card "inactive" but showed with a sign that says something like "work in progress" upon it? In CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

probably the question is not well formulated, I will try to clarify what I meant. I'm making a website which contains several cards that clicking on them some contents shows on new pages. I would like to see the website online soon but some contents are not already done so I would like to show the cards in order to create curiosity but the cards have to appear "inactive" with opacity and with a kind of sign upon them that intends I'm working on them and soon they will be finished. A kind of "man at work sign" upon them. In particular, the cards behind the sign have to appear opacity and the sign on them have to appear normal with no opacity. Sorry if I was verbose. I hope you all understood the problem. Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from your question you want to have a non-opaque child element appear within a semi-opaque parent element. But you have run into the difficulty that all children of a semi-opaque (e.g. opacity=.5) inherit the (lack of) opacity.

If so, the question has an answer at [Make a child element opaque in a div that is not opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832253/make-a-child-element-opaque-in-a-div-that-is-not-opaque)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to share some code? In general that doesn't sound too hard. :)

Without additional information, that's the maximum I was able to understand:

[image: Edit Simple wip card]